# Reverse for 'list-events' not found

Tags: python, html, django, url, crash

Im currently following a Django tutorial to learn views and URLs. I have watched the tutorial over and over and cant see what I am doing wrong.

I receive the error:
Exception Value:

Reverse for 'list-events' not found. 'list-events' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import calendar
from calendar import HTMLCalendar
from datetime import datetime
from .models import Event, Venue
from .forms import VenueForm, EventForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

```
# Create your views here.
# all events is listed in the urls.py hence why the function is named all_events
def update_event(request, event_id):
    event = Event.objects.get(pk=event_id)
    form = EventForm(request.POST, instance=event)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('list-events')
    return render(request, 'events/update_event.html',
                  {'event': event,
                   'form':form})


def add_event(request):

    submitted = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EventForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/add_event?submitted=True')
    else:
        form = EventForm
    if 'submitted' in request.GET:
        submitted = True
    return render(request, 'events/add_event.html', {'form': form, 'submitted': submitted})


def update_venue(request, venue_id):
    venue = Venue.objects.get(pk=venue_id)
    form = VenueForm(request.POST, instance=venue)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('list-venues')

    return render(request, 'events/update_venue.html',
                  {'venue': venue,
                   'form': form})


def search_venues(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST['searched']
        venues = Venue.objects.filter(name__contains=searched)
        return render(request,
                      'events/search_venues.html',
                      {'searched': searched,
                       'venues': venues})
    else:
        return render(request,
                      'events/search_venues.html',
                      {})


def show_venue(request, venue_id):
    venue = Venue.objects.get(pk=venue_id)
    return render(request, 'events/show_venue.html',
                  {'venue': venue})


def list_venues(request):
    venue_list = Venue.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'events/venue.html',
                  {'venue_list': venue_list})

URLS.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('<int:year>/<str:month>/', views.home, name="home"),
    path('events', views.all_events, name='list_events'),
    path('add_venue', views.add_venue, name='add-venue'),
    path('list_venues', views.list_venues, name='list-venues'),
    path('show_venue/<venue_id>', views.show_venue, name='show-venue'),
    path('search_venues', views.search_venues, name='search-venues'),
    path('update_venue/<venue_id>', views.update_venue, name='update-venue'),
    path('add_event', views.add_event, name='add-event'),
    path('update_event/<event_id>', views.update_event, name='update-event'),

event_list.html:

{% extends 'events/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Event  </h1>
<br />

{% for event in event_list %}

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    {{Event}}
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Venue: {{ event.venue }}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">
    <ul>
      <li>Date: {{ event.event_date }}</li>
      <li>Event Venue: {{ event.venue.web }}</li>      
      <li>Manager: {{ event.manager }}</li>
      <li>Desc: {{ event.description }}</li>

      <li>Attendees:<br />
        {% for user in event.attendees.all %}
        {{ user }}<br/>
        {% endfor %}
        </li>
        </ul>
     
      
    



    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-muted">
    <a href="{% url 'update-event' event.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">Update Event</a>
  </div>
</div>



<br /><br />
{% endfor %}

    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: You're including a lot of code that clearly won't have anything to do with what you're trying to ask, make an [mcve]

Comment: you created this `path('events', views.all_events, name='list_events')` but do you actually have `def all_events(..) in your views` ?

Comment: You use `redirect('list-events')` in view function and have `list_events` in urls (note the underscore). Rename your url or replace hyphen with underscore to remove this error. Also, if you're just learning Django, I'd suggest learning class-based views instead of function-based, they are more modern and more DRY in most cases. And you have a typo in `add_event`, in `else` clause it should be `EventForm()`: you should instantiate the form anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your url in the "urls.py" file with the name of "list_events" (note the underscore). In the views you have used it as "list-events" (note the hyphen).

You can fix that by following one of these options:

1.You can change that in the views (by using underscore instead of hyphen):

```
return redirect('list_events')
```

2.Or changing it in the url (by using hyphen instead of underscore):

```
path('events', views.all_events, name='list-events'),
```

Comment: Thank you I cant believe that has just worked. I'm sure I tried that and didn't get the result. Since you are some sort of guru can I further ask. a python script like Sherlock on Git hub. Can that be run by clicking a button in a Django project and return a CSV file. So the HTML page would have a button that is clicked.  How would this be done ?

Comment: I believe you must mention more details of the project you are working on. I can't get what you mean. You might also need to add another question about that, then I or someone else might be able to answer you.